# A continuous function from $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Is there a continuous function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$ such that $f(\cos n)=(n,\frac{1}{n})$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$?

I think this is not possible as if $f$ is continuous then the function $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ given by $g(\cos n)=\frac{1}{n}$ must be continuous. This implies $g(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^{-1}x}$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$. But this function is not defined on odd multiples of $\frac {\pi}{2}$. AM I right?

Comment: I dont see how you can conclude $g(x)=1/\cos^{-1}(x)$. But, note $(\cos n)$ has convergent subsequences, while $((n,1/n))$ does not.

Comment: $g(\cos n) =1/n$ for integer $n$, and what? How it implies that $g(x)=1/\arccos x$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can use, for example, the fact that the continuous image of a compact set is compact, i.e. closed and bounded for $\mathbb{R}^d$. Can you come up with a compact set that contains all the $\cos n$? Can you come up with a compact set that contains all the $f(\cos n)$ values?